# Is it okay to reproduce the work as a teaching assistant?

Tags: teaching-assistant, lecture-teaching-method, lecture-notes

Next week, I need to give a lecture on a topic (say T).

I surveyed over the internet and found excellent video lectures by a professor (Say P).

I learned T thoroughly. I can able to answer any question. I can able to clarify any doubt.

But I may undergo the following problem:

> I may end up in reproducing the same content in all aspects (lecturing
> flow, motivations, examples, notations,...). If any of my students watch the lecture
> series of P after my lecture, they can easily realize that I reproduced the
> same.

Is it a problem or is it normal?

I am feeling it as a problem because of the reason that I feel that my lecture is a subset of the lecture by P. And there is no contribution of mine other than reproducing.

Comment: I guess you tell the students that you reproduce a lecture by P. So why  do you think it should be a problem to them? (I am not saying it is not a problem, I just want to know what exactly you worry about.)

Comment: It looks so because you have found that in the Internet. But a lot of lectures are given every seconds worldwide based on emulation. This is how it works. Don't overthink.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with user11388 that it would be good to "cite" the video you used, but otherwise I wouldn't worry much about this. Truth be told that most of us in academia, in the early part of our teaching career, "emulated" the teaching of our own teachers, especially the ones we most admired. Over time you learn to be more spontaneous, but at the start you try to follow a good model. It is partly what mentoring is about.

However, you will "add value" to the lecture just by being there to answer questions that might arise and to (hopefully) watch the student's reactions so that you can notice difficulties of comprehension.